# log4j архивирование логов

Tags: java, log4j, архивация

Возможно ли настроить `log4j`, что бы он архивировал логи, которые, например, старше двух недель?
Вот конфиг моего аппендера:

```
log4j.appender.systemfile=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.systemfile.File=../log/app.log
log4j.appender.systemfile.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.systemfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.systemfile.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если используете log4j второй версии, используйте паттерн именования файла с добавлением расширения, например: `.gz`. [Согласно документации](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender) поддерживаются следующие типы архивов:  `.gz`, `.zip`, `.bz2`, `.deflate`", `.pack200`, `.xz`, но за исключение `.gz` и `.zip` требуют дополнительных библиотек.

Пример конфига:

```
log4j.appender.loggerId=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender  
log4j.appender.loggerId.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy  
log4j.appender.loggerId.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=application.log  
log4j.appender.loggerId.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=application-.%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz
```